Cannot install Cake Core
I am new to Cake script and I'd like to use the Cake.Npm package to automate a build task.  I am not able to get past loading the Cake.Core package. Google does not provide answers to this basic question.

Script:
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Core&version=4.0.0
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Npm&version=4.0.0

using Cake.Core;
using Cake.Npm;

var target = Argument("target", "Default");

Task("Example").Does(() => {
        var settings = new NpmInstallSettings();

        settings.Global = true;
        settings.Production = false;
        settings.LogLevel = NpmLogLevel.Verbose;

        settings.AddPackage("gulp");
        settings.AddPackage("left-pad");

        NpmInstall(settings);
});

Task("PackageJsonFromDirectory").Does(() => {
        var settings = new NpmInstallSettings();

        settings.LogLevel = NpmLogLevel.Info;
        settings.WorkingDirectory = "usage/";
        settings.Production = true;

        NpmInstall(settings);
});

Task("Default")
    .IsDependentOn("Example")
    .IsDependentOn("PackageJsonFromDirectory");

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// EXECUTION
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

RunTarget(target);

